# Jquery ajax post initiator url is different than actual post request url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having a weird issue I am using jQuery ajax post for posting the form. but whenever form is posted for the first time page is loaded it post the form to a different url. I checked in the console window and after debugging a while I found that the form is initiated to a different url and posted to a different can someone tell what can cause such scenario.

I attached image which shows different url's in initiation and request.

`

```
$("#contact-form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#contact-submit').html('<div class="loader" ></div>');
        $('#contact-submit').prop('disabled', true);
        var url = 'http://example.com/sites/project/public/contact/';
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: {
            name : $('#contact_name').val(),
            email : $('#contact_email').val(),
            subject : $('#contact_subject').val(),
            comment : $('#contact_comment').val()
          },
          success: function(data){
            //$('#contact-alert > p').html(data);
            $('#contact-alert').show();
            $('#contact-submit').html('Submit');
            $('#contact-submit').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#contact-form')[0].reset();   
          },
          fail : function(data){
            $('#contact-alert > p').html('Some error occured try again later.');
            $('#contact-alert').show();
            $('#contact-submit').html('Submit');
            $('#contact-submit').prop('disabled', false);
          }
        });
    });
```

`

[image]

[image]

Comment: @daksh What difference would that make? OP is using `url: url` anyway

Comment: you are right @Terry helping anyways!

Comment: @daksh thanks but I tried it already, not working.

Comment: @Terry could it happen that the user is requesting on 'http://example.com/sites/project/public/contact/' and on that page, he redirects to somewhere else?

Comment: @Terry I can't figure out what is going wrong with it, I debug the issue by putting breakpoints the url is correct the the request is initiated but it goes wrong when the actual request take place.

Comment: Are you sure the endpoint that you're calling is not redirecting requests to somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reason for your misdirection of url is because you are posting on  `url : http://example.com/sites/project/public/contact/` but from there, it redirects to somewhere else. You can share some code of that file if you want us to be of further assistance.